# Scheduled Jasper report runs first time & later it gives empty report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I got a report scheduled to run daily in jasper & which ran first day & later it is giving me empty report. I am passing a parameter & I tested if it is getting passed to ireport & yes it is.
I ran the query in the DB backend & I get some records so the second day output (empty page) is not correct.

The same jasper report worked fine after just I cut & paste the same text from the code basically I didn't change anything, wondering if the first time compilation is making it to  work fine & later I need to recomplile?

But still I could not crack this & any input from your side will be helpful on this.

Comment: Are you talking about JR Server?

Comment: Can you post your JRXML file for us?